# problems like this with just-in-time collection server code with PivotViewer using httpS (SSL)?

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, ssl, https, pivotviewer

We are working on an ASP.NET application at work that uses the just-in-time collection server code with PivotViewer.  Everything works fine using plain http.
However, the ASP.NET application requires users to login which means that it would be better if we use httpS ( SSL).

We needed to install Microsoft URL Rewrite Module http://www.iis.net/download/URLRewrite on the Server that hosts our application.
We also added the following in our web.config to make the automatic 80 -> 443 redirection work

After the  section, and this can not go anywhere else, the following code is added:

```
 <rewrite>
 <rules>
 <rule name="HTTP to HTTPS redirect" stopProcessing="true">
 <match url="(.*)" />
 <conditions>
 <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
 </conditions>
 <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Found" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" />
 </rule>
 </rules>
 </rewrite>
```

We have No web service, No WCF service, No ASMX Service.

However, when we deploy the application with httpS (SSL), the just-in-time collection server code with PivotViewer fails to show anything.  There is No error.  It just Fails to show anything.

May I please know if anyone has had problems like this with just-in-time collection server code with PivotViewer using httpS (SSL)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The contents that are brought up by Pivot Viewer used to be referenced by the just-in-time collection server code using URLs.
In other words, if you wanted a car image jpeg to show up, you would give the just-in-time collection server code something like the following:

http://something.com/ClientBin/Uploads/carimage.jpg

or

https://something.com/ClientBin/Uploads/carimage.jpg

The problem is that the just-in-time collection server code failed to work for the httpS (SSL) URL.

Therefore, we decided to give the just-in-time collection server code the absolute physical Directory Path like the following:

C:\SomethingWebApplication\ClientBin\Uploads\carimage.jpg

Using  absolute physical Directory Path worked with httpS (SSL) but referencing  using httpS (SSL) URLs failed.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the code is issuing a straight `http://<whatever>` call which IIS is then  redirecting to `https://<whatever>` but the code isn't following the redirect.

You might go through your code to ensure it is calling the `https://` version instead of `http://`

Comment: Thanks for responding.I've made changes to Silverlight code and the just-in-time collection server code with PivotViewer in such a way that they dynamically figure out the browser url.Therefore,if it's https then it uses https and if it's http then it is http.Basically, I wanted a smart application that can figure out the url stuff.However, when pivotviewer loads it still fails.Any ideas?